# subquery must return only one column Postgrsql

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to return an object with nested arrays from a PostgreSQL query, how can I do that.? This is what I've tried so far, can someone guide me through it.?

```
SELECT d.id as distributor_id,
       d.name,
       json_agg(json_build_object('route_id', r.id, 'route_name', r.name,'shops',
           json_agg((select * from retailers where retailers."distributorId" = d.id and retailers."routeId" = r.id)) )) as route
FROM users U
         INNER JOIN tsi_distributors td ON U.user_id = td."userUserId" AND td.delete_at IS NULL
         INNER JOIN distributors d ON td."distributorId" = d.id AND d.delete_at IS NULL
         LEFT JOIN routes r on td.id = r."distributorId" AND r.delete_at IS NULL
WHERE U.user_id = 'TSI_84826'
GROUP BY d.id
```

this throws an error tho. `subquery must return only one column`

tying to return an object like this

```
[
  {
    distributor_id: 1,
    name: 'Distributor_1',
    route: [
      {
        route_id: 1,
        route_name: 'Route 1',
        shops: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'shop 1',
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'shop 2',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        route_id: 2,
        route_name: 'Route 2',
        shops: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'shop 3',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use json_agg incorrectly:

1. you should not use result set for subquery as a parameter to json_agg (or any other aggregate function)
2. json_agg accepts json as a parameter, it does not convert anything to json.

Try shifting the json_agg into the subselect like:

```
( select json_agg(to_json(retailers)) 
  from retailers 
  where retailers."distributorId" = d.id 
    and retailers."routeId" = r.id)
```